# Jenkins pipeline file target location

Tags: jenkins, post, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In a delcarative pipeline, I am making an POST API request that requires a file within the request body for uploading. The request looks something like this:

```
def response = httpRequest url: "https://cloud.tenable.com/compliance/export", 
               customHeaders: [[name: 'X-ApiKeys', value: "${ACCESS_KEY}"]],
               httpMode: 'POST',
               acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
               contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
               requestBody:"{"Filedata":????}"
```

This is made with the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) and [this API Syntax](https://developer.tenable.com/reference#file-upload). Assuming I have a zip file called test.zip in my workspace directory, how can I "read" the zip file into the request for uploading? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out the [readFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) keyword from the Pipeline Basic Steps plugin - it enables you to read files from the workspace and control the encoding.

Comment: By the way you also have the `uploadFile` option for the [httpRequest](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) keyword which receives a path and uploads the file. In some situations it can save you the need to load it yourself.

Comment: For small files `readFile` might be Ok, but with large files you will run into resource issues, because it completely reads the file into memory of the Jenkins master. On the contrary, the `uploadFile` option  should be more efficient, as it could stream the file in small blocks (not sure how it's actually implemented, but that's how it's typically done).